# More elegant/shorter way to get values out of a array with hashes?

Tags: ruby

I've got:

```
val = [{uid: '1', ignore: 'i1'}, {:uid: '2', ignore: 'i2'}]
```

Now I want to extract the `:uid` part into a array:

```
arr = []
val.each { |u| u.map { |k,v| arr << v if :uid == k } }
```

Is there a more elegant/shorter way to write the last two lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

```
val = [{uid: '1', ignore: 'i1'}, {uid: '2', ignore: 'i2'}]

arr = val.map { |u| u[:uid] }
```